# Is it possible to set code run when Rails establishes the DB connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

On my web host, I don't have access to change some of the Postgres database configuration settings in the `.conf` file. However, I **do** have access via both the command line and via SQL.

For instance:

```
SET statement_timeout = 600;
```

How can I get Rails to execute such statements whenever it establishes the database connection?

It looks to me like the connection is established by [ActiveRecord::ConectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter.initialize](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter#initialize-instance_method) method.

Without directly editing that method (making it a pain to upgrade anything later), is there some better way to do this?

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
conn.execute "SET statement_timeout = '600';"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `database.yml`:

`timeout: 600`